# How can I concatenate two files, foo1 and foo2, but also insert some text after foo1 and before foo2 from the terminal?

Tags: shell-script, cat

I would like to do something like

```
cat foo1 foo2 | How can I enter sometext from terminal | > foo3
```

where `foo3` contains the contents of `foo1` followed by *`sometext`*, followed by the contents of `foo2`.

My best try so far is

```
cat foo1 - foo2 > foo3
```

but I don't see the data of `foo2` in `foo3`.

Comment: Please provide more information on this, also provide what you have tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: @Chetna C cat foo1 - foo2 > foo3

Comment: but I don't see the data of foo2 in foo3  Thanks

Comment: Your `cat` command in the comments (which, incidentally should be in your question) is a good one. What key did you use to end the input from the terminal and tell `cat` to continue with the next file (`foo2`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command is good:

```
cat foo1 - foo2 > foo3
```

But you shouldn't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate your input from the terminal. This interrupts the entire command. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `echo` and `cat`. Following should work for you

```
echo 'Some text in between' | cat foo1 - foo2 > foo3
```

Comment: Thanks @Chetna for the help, but I needed to enter text from the terminal :)

Answer (score 0):

@Chetna C probably has the answer you're looking for.  But here's another that works in bash:

```
user@hostname ~/test
bash$ echo charlie > foo1

user@hostname ~/test
bash$ echo dennis > foo2

user@hostname ~/test
bash$ cat foo1 <(echo "mac") foo2 > foo3

user@hostname ~/test
bash$ cat foo3
charlie
mac
dennis
```